# how to sort an array based on the contents of another array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, algorithm

I have an array X = [12,14,12,45,12] and another array Y = [34,12,23,47,20]. I am sorting the X array, so now X = [12,12,12,14,45]. Now I want to sort Y as Y = [34,23,20,12,47]. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: 1. What's the logic behind sorting Y
2. Did you try to solve it yourself? Please show some code.

Answer (score 4):

You can build an array of indexes and sort it using a custom comparator function that references X and, then, use that array to "sort" Y:

```js
var X = [12,14,12,45,12];
var Y = [34,12,23,47,20];
var xIndexes = [];
X.forEach((value, index) => xIndexes.push(index));

xIndexes.sort((a, b) => X[a] < X[b] ? -1 : X[a] > X[b] ? 1 : 0);

var newX = [];
var newY = [];

xIndexes.forEach((index) => {
  newX.push(X[index]);
  newY.push(Y[index]);
});

console.log(newX);
console.log(newY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the arrays into a single array. Sort by the original values of `X`, and then separate back into 2 arrays.

```js
const X = [12,14,12,45,12];
const Y = [34,12,23,47,20];

const [Xsorted, Ysorted] =
  X.map((x, i) => [x, Y[i]])
  .sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])
  .reduce((arrs, [x, y]) => {
    const [X, Y] = arrs;
    X.push(x);
    Y.push(y);
    
    return arrs;
  }, [[], []]);
  
console.log(Xsorted);
console.log(Ysorted);
```